# Using Apple's PassKit to replace NFC tags for gate opening

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, nfc, passkit

I am trying to replace an outdated solution of using hardware NFC wristband tags to open gates (buildings for example).

I would like to develop an iOS app that will be able to replace these tags.

I've read a lot about Apple's `PassKit`, and it seems to have the `Pass.NFC` object, which might be relevant to what I need.

I understand I would need to request a special certificate from Apple, but I believe that as far as I follow the guidelines (which I believe I do), I would be able to issue the certificate.

However, I couldn't find any example of using the `Pass.NFC` object, as I get an error when I try to configure the variable:

```
let nfcPass = PKPass.NFC()
```

The error I get is:

```
Type 'PKPass' has no member 'NFC'
```

I aim to fetch the wristband's encryption key using an NFC reader, and then "write" it into the virtual pass, and allow the NFC reader to read the pass from the iPhone.

Does anyone know how can I handle the error I get when trying to configure the NFC pass? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Apple Access is only available to selected partners such as HID and Schlage. I guess, in theory, you could apply to become a partner, but I think at this time Apple is only going to work with major companies. You may be better off replacing the reader hardware with something that already works with iOS and Apple Access such as HID Signo readers. Even then, there are strict requirements on using Apple Access in the wallet and it requires the end user organisation to sign a contract

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for your answer. So as far as I understand, this feature isn't open to the public developer community to use? So the `Pass.NFC` object is irrelevant?

Comment: Correct. Unlike some special entitlements, I don't believe that there is any way for developers to apply